# Configure default folder view for storage connected via MTP

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, usb-storage, mtp

I'm connecting a Samsung GS4 phone to Windows 7 using USB. By default the SGS4 uses MTP for the USB connection. Windows apparently thinks any device using MTP is a media player and only contains media files.

I want the Explorer Window to use the normal Windows Explorer details view, but instead I get columns for "Artist", "Track", etc, and I do not get the columns that I want (like file dates). I can manually reconfigure the columns, but that gets pretty tedious repeating for every folder in a phone's file system.

Is there a way to globally disable the "media type" view and columns, and always have Windows Explorer use the normal file column headings?

Comment: To clarify, I want to cause the MTP devices to always use the "General Items" folder template.   This procedure <http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/15699-folder-template-default.html>  shows how to set the folder template for a traditional drive, but does not work for MTP devices.

Answer (score 2):

Run the following in a .REG file and you will get detailed view for all your MTP drives and more.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell]
"FolderType"="NotSpecified" 

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{5C4F28B5-F869-4E84-8E60-F11DB97C5CC7}]
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"Mode"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works?

Comment: Before using this, I highly recommend backing up your registry or preparing to revert changes such as through System Restore. I recommend not using this in general.

However, you simply need to copy and paste all of the text above into an empty .txt file (with Notepad, for example). Save it, rename the file to have a .reg extension, then run the file.

This interferes with the layout of all folders ("your MTP drives and *more*") which is almost certainly what nobody wants when trying to get their MTP devices to display consistently with other Windows storage.

Comment: Out of curiosity I tried in **Win10** -- apparently it does not work the same way, or it uses different values.  I know all of the above is for **Win7**, but I'm posting this comment in case someone else is wondering if it's worth tinkering in the registry.

Answer (score 0):

In windows 10 You can do this one (below) then logout/login:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{5C4F28B5-F869-4E84-8E60-F11DB97C5CC7}]
"Rev"=dword:00000007
"FFlags"=dword:41200011
"Vid"="{137E7700-3573-11CF-AE69-08002B2E1262}"
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"Sort"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,30,f1,\
  25,b7,ef,47,1a,10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0a,00,00,00,01,00,00,00
"ColInfo"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,fd,df,df,fd,10,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,00,00,18,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,\
  1a,10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0a,00,00,00,78,01,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,1a,\
  10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0e,00,00,00,78,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,1a,10,\
  a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0c,00,00,00,67,00,00,00
"GroupView"=dword:00000000
"GroupByKey:FMTID"="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"
"GroupByKey:PID"=dword:00000000
"GroupByDirection"=dword:00000001
```

but I have used this one for all folders (It resets all bags and set to new layout, which suits my needs

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\1]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\1\Shell]
"SniffedFolderType"="Generic"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\1\Shell\{5C4F28B5-F869-4E84-8E60-F11DB97C5CC7}]
"Rev"=dword:00000007
"FFlags"=dword:41200011
"Vid"="{137E7700-3573-11CF-AE69-08002B2E1262}"
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"Sort"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,30,f1,\
  25,b7,ef,47,1a,10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0a,00,00,00,01,00,00,00
"ColInfo"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,fd,df,df,fd,10,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,00,00,18,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,\
  1a,10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0a,00,00,00,87,01,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,1a,\
  10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0e,00,00,00,78,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,1a,10,\
  a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0c,00,00,00,89,00,00,00
"GroupView"=dword:00000000
"GroupByKey:FMTID"="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"
"GroupByKey:PID"=dword:00000000
"GroupByDirection"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\2]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\2\Shell]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\2\Shell\{5C4F28B5-F869-4E84-8E60-F11DB97C5CC7}]
"Rev"=dword:00000008
"FFlags"=dword:41200011
"Vid"="{65F125E5-7BE1-4810-BA9D-D271C8432CE3}"
"Mode"=dword:00000006
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000002
"IconSize"=dword:00000030
"Sort"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,30,f1,\
  25,b7,ef,47,1a,10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0a,00,00,00,01,00,00,00
"ColInfo"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,fd,df,df,fd,10,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,04,00,00,00,18,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,\
  1a,10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0a,00,00,00,a0,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,1a,\
  10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,04,00,00,00,c8,00,00,00,35,4b,17,9b,ff,40,d2,11,\
  a2,7e,00,c0,4f,c3,08,71,03,00,00,00,80,00,00,00,35,4b,17,9b,ff,40,d2,11,a2,\
  7e,00,c0,4f,c3,08,71,02,00,00,00,80,00,00,00
"GroupCollapseState"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,08,00,00,00,01,00,00,\
  00,08,00,00,00,46,00,6f,00,6c,00,64,00,65,00,72,00,79,00,00,00
"GroupView"=dword:ffffffff
"GroupByKey:FMTID"="{B725F130-47EF-101A-A5F1-02608C9EEBAC}"
"GroupByKey:PID"=dword:00000004
"GroupByDirection"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell]
"FolderType"="NotSpecified"
"MinPos1920x1080x96(1).x"=dword:ffffffff
"MinPos1920x1080x96(1).y"=dword:ffffffff
"MaxPos1920x1080x96(1).x"=dword:ffffffff
"MaxPos1920x1080x96(1).y"=dword:ffffffff
"WinPos1920x1080x96(1).left"=dword:00000089
"WinPos1920x1080x96(1).top"=dword:0000001a
"WinPos1920x1080x96(1).right"=dword:0000033e
"WinPos1920x1080x96(1).bottom"=dword:00000315
"MinPos1440x900x96(1).x"=dword:ffffffff
"MinPos1440x900x96(1).y"=dword:ffffffff
"MaxPos1440x900x96(1).x"=dword:ffffffff
"MaxPos1440x900x96(1).y"=dword:ffffffff
"WinPos1440x900x96(1).left"=dword:00000089
"WinPos1440x900x96(1).top"=dword:0000001a
"WinPos1440x900x96(1).right"=dword:0000033e
"WinPos1440x900x96(1).bottom"=dword:00000315
"MinPos1600x900x96(1).x"=dword:ffffffff
"MinPos1600x900x96(1).y"=dword:ffffffff
"MaxPos1600x900x96(1).x"=dword:ffffffff
"MaxPos1600x900x96(1).y"=dword:ffffffff
"WinPos1600x900x96(1).left"=dword:00000089
"WinPos1600x900x96(1).top"=dword:0000001a
"WinPos1600x900x96(1).right"=dword:0000033e
"WinPos1600x900x96(1).bottom"=dword:00000315
"MinPos1280x960x96(1).x"=dword:ffffffff
"MinPos1280x960x96(1).y"=dword:ffffffff
"MaxPos1280x960x96(1).x"=dword:ffffffff
"MaxPos1280x960x96(1).y"=dword:ffffffff
"WinPos1280x960x96(1).left"=dword:00000089
"WinPos1280x960x96(1).top"=dword:0000001a
"WinPos1280x960x96(1).right"=dword:0000033e
"WinPos1280x960x96(1).bottom"=dword:00000315
"WFlags"=dword:00000000
"ShowCmd"=dword:00000001
"HotKey"=dword:00000000
"NavBar"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,8b,00,00,00,87,00,\
  00,00,31,53,50,53,05,d5,cd,d5,9c,2e,1b,10,93,97,08,00,2b,2c,f9,ae,6b,00,00,\
  00,5a,00,00,00,00,7b,00,36,00,44,00,38,00,42,00,42,00,33,00,44,00,33,00,2d,\
  00,39,00,44,00,38,00,37,00,2d,00,34,00,41,00,39,00,31,00,2d,00,41,00,42,00,\
  35,00,36,00,2d,00,34,00,46,00,33,00,30,00,43,00,46,00,46,00,45,00,46,00,45,\
  00,39,00,46,00,7d,00,5f,00,57,00,69,00,64,00,74,00,68,00,00,00,13,00,00,00,\
  cc,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00

; none specific template
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{5C4F28B5-F869-4E84-8E60-F11DB97C5CC7}]
"Rev"=dword:00000007
"FFlags"=dword:41200011
"Vid"="{137E7700-3573-11CF-AE69-08002B2E1262}"
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"Sort"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,30,f1,\
  25,b7,ef,47,1a,10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0a,00,00,00,01,00,00,00
"ColInfo"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,fd,df,df,fd,10,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,00,00,18,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,\
  1a,10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0a,00,00,00,87,01,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,1a,\
  10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0e,00,00,00,78,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,1a,10,\
  a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0c,00,00,00,89,00,00,00
"GroupView"=dword:00000000
"GroupByKey:FMTID"="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"
"GroupByKey:PID"=dword:00000000
"GroupByDirection"=dword:00000001

; Docs template
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{7d49d726-3c21-4f05-99aa-fdc2c9474656}]
"Rev"=dword:00000007
"FFlags"=dword:41200011
"Vid"="{137E7700-3573-11CF-AE69-08002B2E1262}"
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"Sort"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,30,f1,\
  25,b7,ef,47,1a,10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0a,00,00,00,01,00,00,00
"ColInfo"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,fd,df,df,fd,10,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,00,00,18,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,\
  1a,10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0a,00,00,00,87,01,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,1a,\
  10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0e,00,00,00,78,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,1a,10,\
  a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0c,00,00,00,89,00,00,00
"GroupView"=dword:00000000
"GroupByKey:FMTID"="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"
"GroupByKey:PID"=dword:00000000
"GroupByDirection"=dword:00000001

; Music template
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{94d6ddcc-4a68-4175-a374-bd584a510b78}]
"Rev"=dword:00000007
"FFlags"=dword:41200011
"Vid"="{137E7700-3573-11CF-AE69-08002B2E1262}"
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"Sort"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,30,f1,\
  25,b7,ef,47,1a,10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0a,00,00,00,01,00,00,00
"ColInfo"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,fd,df,df,fd,10,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,00,00,18,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,\
  1a,10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0a,00,00,00,87,01,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,1a,\
  10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0e,00,00,00,78,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,1a,10,\
  a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0c,00,00,00,89,00,00,00
"GroupView"=dword:00000000
"GroupByKey:FMTID"="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"
"GroupByKey:PID"=dword:00000000
"GroupByDirection"=dword:00000001

; Pics template
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{b3690e58-e961-423b-b687-386ebfd83239}]
"Rev"=dword:00000007
"FFlags"=dword:41200011
"Vid"="{137E7700-3573-11CF-AE69-08002B2E1262}"
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"Sort"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,30,f1,\
  25,b7,ef,47,1a,10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0a,00,00,00,01,00,00,00
"ColInfo"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,fd,df,df,fd,10,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,00,00,18,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,\
  1a,10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0a,00,00,00,87,01,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,1a,\
  10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0e,00,00,00,78,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,1a,10,\
  a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0c,00,00,00,89,00,00,00
"GroupView"=dword:00000000
"GroupByKey:FMTID"="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"
"GroupByKey:PID"=dword:00000000
"GroupByDirection"=dword:00000001

; Video template
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{5fa96407-7e77-483c-ac93-691d05850de8}]
"Rev"=dword:00000007
"FFlags"=dword:41200011
"Vid"="{137E7700-3573-11CF-AE69-08002B2E1262}"
"Mode"=dword:00000004
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000001
"IconSize"=dword:00000010
"Sort"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,30,f1,\
  25,b7,ef,47,1a,10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0a,00,00,00,01,00,00,00
"ColInfo"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,fd,df,df,fd,10,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,00,00,18,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,\
  1a,10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0a,00,00,00,87,01,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,1a,\
  10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0e,00,00,00,78,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,1a,10,\
  a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0c,00,00,00,89,00,00,00
"GroupView"=dword:00000000
"GroupByKey:FMTID"="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"
"GroupByKey:PID"=dword:00000000
"GroupByDirection"=dword:00000001
```