# Windows 8 Desktop Icons in Tile View

Tags: windows-8, desktop, icons

I appear to have some how placed my icons on my desktop in Tile View.  I cannot for the life of me figure out how to restore the icons to their normal appearance.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is a printscreen of a portion of my desktop so you can see what I'm talking about:

[image]

Comment: Start `regedit.exe` and navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\1\Desktop`. What are the `LogicalViewMode` and `Mode` values set to?

Comment: LogicalViewMode = 5 and Mode = 8. Both are Hexadecimal and REG_DWORD if that helps too.

Comment: @and31415 I managed to fix the problem with you pointing me to these 2 keys. Thank you very much for the guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type `regedit.exe`, and click **OK**.
2. Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\1\Desktop`.
3. Leave the registry editor windows open. Then, while pressing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys together, right-click the taskbar, and choose **Exit Explorer** from the context menu.
4. Go back to the registry editor, and change the `LogicalViewMode` and `Mode` values to `3` and `1`, respectively (i.e. the default values).
5. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to bring up the Task Manager.
6. Click on **File > Run new task**. Type `explorer.exe`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

### Additional information

Here are the possible values:

```
LogicalViewMode | Value | Description
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Details         |   1   | Details view
Tiles           |   2   | Tiles view
Icons           |   3   | Icons view
List            |   4   | List view (Windows 7 and later)
Content         |   5   | Content view (Windows 7 and later)
```

­

```
Mode            | Value | Description
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Icon            |   1   | Medium-size icons
Small icon      |   2   | Small icons (seems unused)
List            |   3   | Object names are displayed in a list view
Details         |   4   | Object names and other selected information are shown
Thumbnail       |   5   | Thumbnail icons
Tiles           |   6   | Large icons
Thumbstrip      |   7   | Display icons in a filmstrip format (XP only)
Content         |   8   | Content mode (Windows 7 and later)
```

## References

- [FOLDERLOGICALVIEWMODE enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [FOLDERVIEWMODE enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @Lyynk424 I've added some info about the different values. For example, the desktop has `LogicalViewMode` and `Mode` values set to `3` and `1`, which means it's displayed in icons view and using medium-size icons.

Comment: I changed mine to list view and now I can't arrange my icons.  They are lined up horizontally across both desktops.  Ideas?

Comment: @and31415, this has been one of the most awesome docs that I have pointed people to forever; however, as of Windows 10 (1703) this trick no longer works, is there any update to it that will make it continue working? I would personally appreciate it, and I am sure there are many others that would as well. I had this working just fine on Windows 10 for all builds until 1703 (aka Creator Update). Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. On the desktop, Hold 
`Ctrl` > Roll Mousewheel **`Up`**/ **`Down`** to Increase/Decrease Icon size ;)

Comment: Using the mouse wheel on the desktop you can only adjust the icon size, but the display mode won't change.